# How to create boxplots (efficiently) from a list of data frames?

Tags: r

I have some `data.frame`s:

```
# Sample data
a <- data.frame(c(1:10), c(11:20))
names(a) <- c("A", "B")
b <- data.frame(sqrt(1:200), sqrt(201:400))
names(b) <- c("A", "B")
c <- data.frame(log2(1:500), log2(501:1000))
names(c) <- c("A", "B")
```

I would like to make `boxplot`s over all `data.frames` (so there should be 6 boxplots in the output)

I tried the following code:

```
abc <- list(a, b, c)
names(abc) <- c("a", "b", "c")
boxplot(abc$a[[1]], abc$a[[2]], abc$b[[1]],abc$b[[2]],abc$c[[1]],abc$c[[2]])
```

It worked, but it was really clumsy. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: `do.call(boxplot, list(unlist(abc, recursive=FALSE)))`

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 for providing a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short and sweet answer is definately @hrbrmstr's comment. Here's a slightly longer `ggplot` solution.

```
library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
library(ggplot2)
df <- lapply(names(abc),function(x)cbind(name=x,abc[[x]]))
df <- melt(do.call(rbind,df),id="name")
ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(~name)
```

[image]